# Typescript and react conditional render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to typescript and not an expert in FE development. I've encountered issue that seems pretty basic, but I failed to found any solution. Maybe I just don't know how to google it properly.
In react component I have a button, that is disabled on some condition, which triggers a component's function:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

type DraftCompany = {
    id: null
    name: string,
};

type Company = Omit<DraftCompany, 'id'> & {
    id: number;
};

type Props = {
    company: Company | DraftCompany,
    onDeleteCompany: (companyId: number) => void,
}

class CompanyRow extends Component <Props> {
    handleDeleteCompany = () => {
        this.props.onDeleteCompany(this.props.company.id);
    };

    render = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.props.company.name}</div>
                <div>
                    <button disabled={this.props.company.id === null} onClick={this.handleDeleteCompany}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CompanyRow;
```

I am getting typescript error on calling `this.props.onDeleteCompany(this.props.company.id);` that says that there is a chance I will pass `null` as a parameter. I fully understand why typescript gives me this error, the question is: **what would be the best way to deal with this error?**

I have found 3 ways:

1) Add 'if' guard

```
handleDeleteCompany = () => {
        if (this.props.company.id) {
            this.props.onDeleteCompany(this.props.company.id);
        }
    };
```

It works, but I don't like the idea of adding such guards into every function, if someone removes `disabled` logic, I want to receive console error telling me about it immediately, not to have it be silently swallowed. In my project I have a lot of such code that relies on render, I doubt it is a best practice to add such checks everywhere. Maybe I am wrong.

2) Apply `as` to field operator:

```
 handleDeleteCompany = () => {
        this.props.onDeleteCompany(this.props.company.id as number);
    };
```

It works, but looks kinda hacky.

3) Apply `as` operator to whole object and pass it to function:

```
 <button disabled={this.props.company.id === null} 
         onClick={() => this.handleDeleteCompany(this.props.company as Company)}/>
```

```
 handleDeleteCompany = (company: Company) => {
        this.props.onDeleteCompany(company.id as number);
    };
```

It works, but it looks like I am unnecessary passing the value I could have grabbed in function itself from props. I am not sure it is best practice to do such things.

I am sure there should be some pure typescript solution like defining Props type as a union or using conditional types with some combination of `any` and `never`. But I haven't figured it out .

Here is a playground: 
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBhCcCAOyWJgF84AzKQuAcilQwYG4BYAKG5gE8wSOABEoKajALgUxPnAC8ubnBVxgAEwBccYgFcANvuWriKEEm0BnGFGDEA5pm4VOPLv0FwpYGXMUB5EGAYAB5RcUlCH1lsBg0GAD44ADIlLlU1LR1dEAAjJChXF25eASEABTowSwU0jLQo321vXzgAHxExCRaY4xUSYSR9JBgkHr5tAAoG6VkASSy9PIKASgUkgDcIDScuChKuNH0USxrxhAgAdzgkAA9R4nUzqJIyeBDKiGqknD64AAsZOphoNhqNxrVJmt5D8-hkYP9gJYAHRgKoogZDEZjRqySYIpGo9HImbRPjIjQrVwZYpuDLMR4FSHQ2HpDKqZgwXRQYhwSZw9kqELqYAbBICwUZYWihI4AkotFfFGk3zI0zmCghAD0IrFEslQt14rZBtNcBCuV0MBgJDgIssKFyw3U8jliIVxJVsgp6gU8kUekMVBIeH0wDQAGtXfLkYDHiCseDcXwKFrjWbBdqjfqpTqZfqVn99nsDndILA7UhqCgDPBzlc2EA)

Comment: The question is what does the `onDeleteCompany` do. Does it accept `id` to be `null`?

Comment: @kinduser It doesn't accept null, always number.

Comment: Then the _if guard_ is the way to go.

Comment: @kinduser Thanks for opinion! So we shouldn't rely on "ifs" in render and always add a check in function itself? Would you advice the same guard if it is not typescript, just regular js component?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the compile to assume a value is never `null` or `undefined` with the `!` operator:

```
 handleDeleteCompany = () => {
        this.props.onDeleteCompany(this.props.company.id!);
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about it! Is it the best option in described situation in your opinion?

Comment: Why to force ts to compile and assume that `id` is never null even if there's an interface that actually assumes that `id` can be null. It barely contains any sense.

Comment: As long as you can be sure that `id` is will never be null there, I would say `!` is feasable. I think it expresses your intent more clearly than the typecast or an `if` without `else`.
Use `!` only in edge cases and when you are 100% sure and when you are in control of all call sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think based on your requirement

> if someone removes disabled logic, I want to receive console error telling me about it immediately

There is a very simple solution that makes perfect sense, simply change your `onDeleteCompany` type from `(companyId: number) => void` to `(companyId: number | null) => void`, then TypeScript will be happy.

It also semantically make sense to you as you want the runtime report this error when `companyId` is null. Then you should allow companyId with `null` to be passed in as parameter.