# Syncrohize react conditional rendering and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In this component I trigger post loading using `postsActions.getPost('1')` and put it into the redux store. `useSelector` catches it and triggers `PostPage` rerender, now with header and button with `onClickUse` function attached that uses `post.header` along with the post object that it uses:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { postsActions } from '../../store/Posts';

import styles from './PostPage.module.scss';

const PostPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const post = useSelector((state) => state.post);

  const onClickUse = () => {
    console.log(`See? I am used only when post is rendered`);
    console.log(`So it's fine if I use it here: ${post.header}`);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(postsActions.getPost('1'));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {
        post &&
        <div>
          <h1>{post.header}</h1>
          <button onClick={onClickUse}>Click me</button>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostPage;
```

The problem is that typescript yells inside `onClickUse` at me that `post` can be `undefined`. How do I then synchronize React conditional rendering functionality and typescript without hacks from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565524/typescript-and-react-conditional-render), like `!`, `as` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can inline

```
<div className={styles.container}>
      {
        post &&
        <div>
          <h1>{post.header}</h1>
          <button onClick={() => {
               console.log(`See? I am used only when post is rendered`);
               console.log(`So it's fine if I use it here: ${post.header}`);
          }}>Click me</button>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
```

or if you don't want inline functions in render, you should create a component with not falsy `post` in props and conditionally render it.

Typescript (in handler) knows nothing about render logic in your example